# Mysql search through each word

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Let's say I have a column 'x' with a record: 'one two hello five'.
I want to search for a specific word (f.e. 'hello') and if it exists - give this record as a result.

1. I've tried 'SELECT (...) WHERE x LIKE 'hello' - no matches
2. I dont want to use 'SELECT (...) WHERE x LIKE '%hello%' - cause it will give me also records where 'hello' can be included in another word (f.e. 'rhellog' - which I dont want to)
3. I dont want regex 'RLIKE '[[:<:]]hello[[:>:]]' - cause it is to slow

Is there any other option, which will be searching for an exact word inside given column, but is not as slow as regex ?

Comment: using `regex` is your best option.

Comment: Use the full text search capabilities if you want speed.

Comment: @gordon - what do U mean ?

Comment: See my answer regarding full text search in MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 4):

If you want speed, use the full text search index.  If the column contains something like tags separated by spaces, then you have the wrong data structure and need another table.

You can do what you want with `like`, assuming a consistent word separator:

```
where concat(' ', x, ' ') like '% hello %'
```

But this won't be much faster than the regex version.  And the regex version is more general because it allows more word separators.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x LIKE '% hello %
```

with spaces on either side of `hello`?

Comment: thats a cool idea! But wont work if word is first or last word in sentence (no space)

Comment: Then use an or for example...   'WHERE x LIKE '% hello % or WHERE x LIKE '%hello % or WHERE x LIKE '% hello%'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT (...) WHERE x LIKE '% hello %' or x LIKE 'hello %' or x LIKE '% hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, with use cases like this, you should think if MySQL is the best database for the job. You can search for `%hello%` or as others have suggested you can use regex. But you have to realize that these are all going to be slow compared to other databases that actually let you search text.

Your next option is to use `match(column) against ('hello')` which if you have the latest version can leverage the [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

Your best option will is to really evaluate your use case. If this is for a small amount of data then any of the above will probably work. But if you have millions of documents and millions of transactions then your best option would be to use something like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) where it index words using Lucene.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, using `REGEXP` is slow, and so is using `LIKE` with wildcards.

Your requirements are solved well by a **fulltext index**. This is a feature built into MySQL: [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html), or alternatively you can index your data independently using a tool like Apache Solr or Sphinx Search.

You will probably find useful the presentation I made comparing different fulltext search solutions for MySQL.

- Slides: [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql)
- Webinar video: [Full Text Search Throwdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Sa7TvXnQwY)

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE x LIKE '%hello%'
HAVING x RLIKE '[[:<:]]hello[[:>:]]'
```

Explanation:

1. The `LIKE` is faster, but gets some rows you don't want.
2. The `RLIKE` is applied only to the ones filtered by the LIKE, so its sluggishness is not too much of a problem.

(Yes, `FULLTEXT` would be much faster.)